Where do the Rebel and Imperial symbols appear onscreen in the Original Trilogy?
On an episode of the podcast Star Wars Minute, one of the hosts puts forward a tongue-in-cheek theory about the intent of the Rebel and Imperial emblems, summarized here:

Rebellion and Empire emblems
From the brilliant mind of host Alex Robinson in SWM 114.
The emblems that are used by the Rebellion and the Empire in the later movies are not worn by everyone in Star Wars, so they must have been adopted after the Battle of Yavin as follows:

The Death Star is destroyed by Luke Skywalker, so:

The Rebellion adopted the hero's (that is, Luke's) symbol as their own - like Robert E. Lee in the American Civil War.
The Empire adopted The Death Star crew's emblem to commemorate the destruction of The Death Star and the significant loss of life. Never forget - like 9/11.



(Source: https://wiki.starwarsminute.com/index.php?title=SWM-Canon#Rebellion_and_Empire_emblems)

Obviously, both ideas thoroughly conflict with subsequent Legends and Canon material. But I'm curious where else we see both emblems onscreen during the Original Trilogy. The only examples I can think of offhand are on Luke's and Jek Porkins' helmets for the Rebels, and on TIE pilot and Death Star technicians' helmets for the Empire—is there anywhere else they appear?

Almost all of the pilots are wearing the symbol somewhere on their uniforms or helmets in ANH. I count at least four just in this one picture; https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/image_775adb3b.jpeg

@Valorum Of course that picture isn’t from ANH, but it is original trilogy.

In brief, in the Original Trilogy the Rebel 'Firebird' and Empire 'cog' emblem only appear on a very few occasions, and always on costumes. The original designer, John Mollo stated (in Star Wars Insider #98) that he initially designed both for helmets, then decided that both were the generic symbols of each side, which is why they also appear on arm-patches.

Q. I'm looking for help in finding the artist responsible for the Galactic Empire emblem (cog) and the Rebel Alliance symbol back in the 1970s. Could it have  been John Mollo (Costume Designer of A New Hope) or maybe Joe Johnson, or some other artist?
A. The circular black and white logo used on the Imperial helmets was designed by me, and was based on a series of sketches working out the possible use of shapes occurring in 18th Century fortifications. The Rebel logo I take to be the one on the Fighter Pilots' helmets. This was again designed by me - no particular sources used this time.*

You can see some of Mollo's alternate designs here for the symbols from his sketchbooks, auctioned in 2018:


A New Hope
The 'Empire' symbol first makes its appearance in Star Wars: A New Hope, adorning the hats and shoulders of the firing-control workers and turbolaser operators on the Death Star.



Similarly, the 'Rebel Firebird' is seen on the helmets of various pilots. Not just Luke, but others around him.



Empire Strikes Back
The 'Firebird' appears on the Rebel pilots helmets.

The 'Empire' symbol makes an appearance on the helmet of General Veers' AT-AT driver and various technicians on the Star Destroyer bridge. As before, it's used very sparingly and only really among operators of a certain rank.


Return of the Jedi
The 'Empire' symbol is once again seen on various technician's uniforms on the new Death Star II and ground base on Endor


The 'Firebird' is once again seen only on the pilot's helmets.


Hmm.  12 screen caps...  Yeah, that's probably worth a point. :D

@DavidW - If something's worth doing, it's worth doing with colossal overkill

Pretty cool that the Empire "cog" is based on the shapes of fortifications! I was just reading about bastions and Renaissance fortifications very recently.
